# Output in one row by using stuff function

Tags: sql-server

What I want is one row,
although I tried to use the `cast` function but not much success. Can someone tell me how I can achieve this MS SQL server as in oracle we do have certain functions like `stragg`

I'm getting the following result:

```
Tenancy No Property NO usercode name       Address   person no  lead tenant
123    1234        12345 MR  Rose   Temp add  1          1  
123    1234        12345 MRS Rose   Temp add  2          0
```

but I want something like this:

```
123    1234        12345 MR  Rose ; MRS ROSE   Temp add  1 ; 0
```

Here is my code:

```
Select   distinct(t."prhst-occ-num") as "TENANCY_REF",         
  per."pr-seq-no"   as "PROPERTY-REF-NO" ,         
  pr."user-cde"     as "USER_CDE",         
  **/*CAST( SUBSTRING( stuff ((
   select distinct(',' + per."fnam")
   From   per per ,
                prhst  prh,
                aTNCY   t 
   where  prh."per-num"=per."num"
   and  t."prhst-occ-num"=prh."occ-num"  
   and  prh."lead-tenant" in (0,1)
   for XML Path('')
   ), 1, 1, ''),1,500) as nvarchar(500)) as "FIRSTNAMES",*/**

         per."fnam" + '-' + per."snam"  as "FULL NAME",  
         pr."addr" + ' '+ pr."postcode"     as  "FULL ADDRESS" ,
         prh."tenu-cde",
  prh."per-num"                 as  "PERSON NUMBER",
  prh."lead-tenant"        as  "LEAD TENANT"   ,
From     TNCY   t, 
         PR     pr,   
         PRHST  prh,
         per    per  
Where    t."prhst-occ-num"=prh."occ-num"
  and    pr."seq-no"=prh."pr-seq-no"
  and    per."num"=prh."per-num"
order by 1,2
```

Answer (score 0):

So you'd like to squash multiple rows into one text column.  The `for xml` clause can do  that, but you usually apply it to a subquery.  For example:

```
select  TextColumn + ';' as [text()]
from    (
        select FirstName + ' ' + LastName as TextColumn
        from Customers
        ) sub
for xml path('')
```

If you input a table with names, this query prints one row:

```
Jeffrey Jones;Andrei Voronkov;George Boole;Kurt Gödel
```

You can replace the subquery with any other query, for example:

```
select  TextColumn + ';' as [text()]
from    (
        select  t.[prhst-occ-num] + ' ' + per.fnam + '-' + 
                    per.snam as TextColumn
        from    TNCY   t, 
                PR     pr,   
                .....
        order by
                t.[prhst-occ-num]
        ) sub
for xml path('')
```

Comment: Hi,

I have removed the order by but getting the following error

Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ';' to data type int.

Thanks

Comment: Use `cast(col1 as varchar(25))` before concatenating a number onto a string.  For example, `cast(t."prhst-occ-num" as varchar(10)) + ' ' + per."fnam"`